# How to get the last anchor element of a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in need of obtaining the very last anchor of a website, regardless of the DOM tree structure.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lastAnchor = $(this).find("a:last-child");
    alert(lastAnchor);
});
```

However I get all the last anchors that exist inside any element, which contains at least one anchor in it. I understand that this can be converted into an array and from there one may extract the last element... but that's just not the right approach. So what **is** the right approach?

**Fun fact:** 
After messing around with the selectors for some time I came up with:

```
$(this).find("a:last-child").find(":last-child")
```

Which lead to the obvious improvement:

```
$(this).find("a:last-child :last-child")
```

But I find this solution to be both **inefficient** and **cumbersome**. I refuse to believe that a better selector does not exist.

I think I am missing *something obvious* but it hasn't hit me yet.

Can anyone please enlighten me to whether there is a better way to do this or am I crying wolf for no reason?

**EDIT: Bonus Round**

Very good answers have been posted to this question thus far, all along the lines of CSS/JavaScript/JQuery. However could you kindly add whether or not your answer is cross browser compatible?

Comment: "but that's just not the right approach" - Why not ?

Comment: because I believe a better selector should exist for this, don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward javascript is:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var lastAnchor = anchors[(anchors.length - 1)];
```

This is cross-browser compatible across all browsers all the way back to those browsers which understand only DOM Level 1 (ie. circa 2000 - Internet Explorer 5 and Netscape 6).

Comment: Agreed... however how is this better than a CSS selector for example, `last` or `last-of-type`? Good answer by the way

Comment: Only that unadulterated javascript is always going to be fractionally quicker.

Comment: your answer is great, but the complete solution would involve CSS too using `:last`. I think given the fact that both you and tabz100 answered correctly, it goes without saying both your answers are the best ones. Feel free to add CSS here and enjoy the correct answer bonus... but that would take away from tabz100's answer in a way

Comment: Javascript requires no CSS selector to obtain the very last anchor in a given web document.

Comment: I agree with you completely, I think it is safe to say your solution is the most efficient one, however it does not escape the fact that having `:last` is a very good solution on its own as well. Either ways good job mate!

Comment: You're most welcome, @AGE. There's nothing wrong with turning to jQuery when it's more efficient, elegant and saves time, but when the bare-bones javascript solution is as straightforward (and cross-browser compatible) as this, then, "Javascript first" is a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try `$('a:last');`

Comment: Which is best, `last` or `last-of-type`?

Comment: In order for it to know what is last it still must scan all a's. BTW the last() ( function) implementation is just like `this.eq(-1);` I don't see any benefit here as opposed to get all a's and then take the last one.

Comment: @RoyiNamir in that case one could argue that `last` is the direct best choice for the question I made

Comment: @AGE If you're talking bout speed , (with jquery) then read what jquery says : "_To achieve the best performance when using :last to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":last")._".

Comment: @RoyiNamir that much I know :-) but from what I read from Shane `:last` is a jQuery css extension, is that true or is it really a CSS selector?

Comment: @AGE It is an extension. As you can see ( it is not in the list:) http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: @RoyiNamir in that case `:last-of-type` should be the right approach right? As long as it is well supported cross browsers

Comment: @AGE `a:last-of-type` has some of the same drawbacks as `a:last-child` in that it will get you all cases of an anchor tag that are the last anchor tags in their parents. If there is more than one in the page, it will return a list.

Comment: @AGE no. **last-of-type is not going to help**. here  , you expect one red but you see two :http://jsbin.com/licayekodo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @RoyiNamir nice! Therefore it would be wise to say `:last` is the best solution, as well as a JavaScript alternative/fallback

Comment: @AGE Yes.(which is exactly what my solution was suggesting. ( the deleted one))

Comment: @RoyiNamir feel free to edit this one, add the JavaScript fallback on it, everybody happy... thanks for the awesomeness!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `a:last-of-type`. Read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/

Comment: Which is best, `last` or `last-of-type`?

Comment: @AGE `:last-of-type` is the proper CSS selector. `:last` is a jQuery extension.

Comment: got it, I know for a fact CSS selectors > JS/JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like `$("a").last()`

This will look at all anchor elements in the page and give you the very last one that is retrieved.

Using just CSS selectors is tricky, since those tend to be dependant on the DOM arrangement, and you want the selector to be DOM agnostic. For example the `a:last-child` selector will only return an anchor tag that is the last element in its parent. If the last anchor on a page is not the last element in its parent, using that selector may not be helpful to you.

Comment: That's nice I missed this on the jQuery docs, but I think a direct CSS selector is a better choice... good answer regardless

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-last-child()`. Its pretty useful when you want the last or 2nd to last.

```
$(this).find("a:nth-last-child(1)")
```

https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/

http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/

Comment: I keep on asking around each person who answers... which is best, `last` or `last-of-type`?

Comment: "I get all the last anchors that exist inside any element, which contains at least one anchor in it." [http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/o5y9959b/1/)