# identify and jump to last anchor on document

Tags: javascript, anchor, hashtag

```
function goToPrevAnchor() {
var anchors = document.anchors;
var loc = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
var prevAnchorName;

 // Get name of the current anchor from the hash
var anchorName = window.location.hash.replace(/#/,'');

if (anchorName) {

// Find current element in anchor list, then
// go back to prev anchor name, or if at last anchor, set to first
for (var i=0, iLen=anchors.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (anchors[i].name == anchorName) {
    prevAnchorName = anchors[--i % iLen].name;
    break;
  }
 }
}

// If there was no anchorName or no match,
// set prevAnchorName to last anchor name
if (!prevAnchorName) {
prevAnchorName = anchors[(anchors.length - 1)].name; //this is the issue
}

// Go to new URL
window.location.href = loc + '#' + prevAnchorName;
}
```

I got this part, anchors[(anchors.length - 1)] from another stackoverflow question. [How to get the last anchor element of a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555134/how-to-get-the-last-anchor-element-of-a-website)

Here is the html

```
<li><a href="#1">Go to 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Go to 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">Go to 3</a></li>

<button id="prev_btn" class="fixed" onclick="goToPrevAnchor()">Prev</button>
```

(yes, I know I need to change onClick to a function.)

The way I am understanding the script I've hacked/assembled together is that if url hash is at the very beginning & the button is clicked, the url hash will be pointed to the end of the very last anchor tag; at least that's my intention.

And I can't really comprehend why it's not working as my vanilla javascript knowledge is very limited.

Please don't tell me to just go back to jQuery.  This is literally the last part of the UI I am building and after this, I am completely done.  I don't want to go back & load jQuery just for this one line of code I can't get it to work.

Please have mercy on me. haha  Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at goToPrevAnchor (  "file name & line )
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

This doesn't really tell me anything as I already know that onclick causes the error.

Comment: When the current anchor is the first anchor, `anchors[--i % iLen].name` tries access `anchors[-1]`. This doesn't exist, so it's trying to get `undefined.name`, which causes the error.

Comment: That expression assumes that `%` will wrap around from a negative to the end, but it doesn't work that way. I consider it a language design error, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @Barmar, ok.  Is there at least any way to prevent the button from firing if it's at the very beginning?

I've tried visibility = "hidden" & disabled = true; neither works. (my js knowledge is elementary so that's all I can think of)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just check for this case in your loop. `if (i == 0) { prevAnchorName = ...;} else { prevAnchorName = ...;}`

Comment: huh? what should be the value of prevAnchorName? can you be more specific? that seems like the same logic as if (!prevAnchorName)  

I don't see how that's any different.

Comment: It's the same value you currently assign in `if (!prevAnchorName)`. Don't you understand the logic of your own code? I posted an answer a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean.  You tell me the logic is wrong.  Ok.  But you are telling me to do exactly the same; just in a different way.  

Have I misunderstood this?

Comment: @Barmar, oh I am sorry.  It's working somehow.  But I still don't see how (i == 0) is any different than if (!nextAnchorName).

To me, both are stating the same fact.  

While I don't quite fully understand why one works & the other doesn't, I thank you for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: In your code, it's never getting to `if (!nextAnchorName)` because the error in the loop stops the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the anchor that's found is the first one, your code tries to access `anchors[-1].name`, which causes an error.

Put the check for finding the first anchor in your loop, not after the loop.

```
for (var i=0, iLen=anchors.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (anchors[i].name == anchorName) {
    if (i == 0) {
        prevAnchorName = anchors[(anchors.length - 1)].name;
    } else {
        prevAnchorName = anchors[i - 1].name;
    }
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

You could also do this check before the loop, and start the loop at `i = 1`.

```
if (anchors[0].name == anchorName) {
    prevAnchorName = anchors[(anchors.length - 1)].name;
} else {
    for (var i=1, iLen=anchors.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        if (anchors[i].name == anchorName) {
            prevAnchorName = anchors[i - 1].name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would write it as `if (anchors[i].name == anchorName) { continue; }` to avoid nesting all the ifs. Other than that this looks good :)

Comment: That should be `!=`

Comment: Thank you OptimusCrime for your insight & thank you Barmar for your explanation.  I think I am beginning to understand the fault in the original logic.  I think I am just too tired.  I will sleep on it & take a look at it again tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: Ups, sorry @Barmar `!=` was what I meant.